# How to fake DNS switch

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, reverse-dns

So, I'm moving my website to another server and I had to change name servers for my domain.

It will take some time to propagate, but I was wondering if it were possible to trick my computer into thinking that domain name is already related to another server.

I tried to point my domain name to new server ip in my hosts file but I guess that isn't how it works. (I'm on windows btw)

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/hosts-file-in-windows

Comment: Using the hosts file should work just fine.

Comment: But you may have to restart your browser.

Comment: Yes, I had to clear cache for chrome -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1

Open an Administrator Notepad (Start > Type 'Notepad' > Right-click > Click 'Run as Administrator')

Then File > Open

Browse to C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Append a line to the file like so:

```
1.2.3.4 example.com
1.2.3.4 subdomain.example.com
```

(Yes, you have to do every subdomain)

If you want it to go back to using the nameservers, remove the line you added in another Administrator Notepad.

### Method 2

Install [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Once installed and opened, you should be able to add a temporary host resolution by going into Tools > HOSTS and see a screen like [this](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/images/HOSTS/HOSTS.png).

So it is the same as above:

```
1.2.3.4 example.com
1.2.3.4 subdomain.example.com
```

The advantage to Fiddler is that once it is closed, the routes set in HOSTS don't work anymore, so it is useful if you don't want to have your changes become permanent.